# error when importing cgi

Tags: python, python-3.x, cgi

i am running python 3.2.6 on an a2hosting shared server. when i do

```
import cgi
```

i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/cgi.py", line 38, in <module>
from email.parser import FeedParser
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
from email import message
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/email/message.py", line 19, in <module>
from email import header
File "/usr/lib64/python3.2/email/header.py", line 17, in <module>
import email.base64mime
EOFError: EOF read where not expected
```

how can i solve this? i do not have root access.

**edit:**

this is the answer i got from a2hosting support:

Hello, Unfortunately, we really cannot provide development assistance here. This is quite above and beyond our scope of support. **While we'd like to be able to provide support for each and every program, language, script, etc, that comes out, it's just physically impossible to do so.** You'll want to work with your development team, or the applications developers to ensure that this is something that's investigated thoroughly.

Comment: You seem to have a bad `.pyc` file for `email.base64mime`, perhaps one from the wrong Python version.

Answer (score 0):

i circumvented the issue by installing a different version of python, following this: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/using-a-newer-version-of-python